# Securing the decoding algorithm - SQL or on SERVER side

Tags: asp.net, sql, security, server-side

In given database Table login creds are:
username,password,decoded ip address

to validate login i need to decode the ip address string,
where it is mostly secure to decode it:
1)sql side - programability layer
2)server side - hardcoded in code layer

I don't care about maintenance, mostly important is securing the decoding algorithm.

I found an article saying that if database was hacked or certain person succeed to connect to it ,if the decoding algorithm will be on sql side, it will be revealed, so for this reason
if algorithm will be hardcoded then it could be revealed only if source code would be stolen.
Do you agree?

Comment: Why would you even use a decoding algorithm? Why not use a hash (or better: [KDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function)) like the rest of the world does? No need for decoding nor decoding algorithms. There *are* situations where you might need access to the plain-text password but I *highly* doubt that is the case here. Relying on your "algorithm" to be kept "secret" implies [Security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_by_obscurity) and a home-grown "encryption algorithm"; neither of those are a good idea (actually: a big no-no).

Comment: because the decoded ip address actually has 3 other text data that are needed and being updated all the time...again...for security reasons. think that its text1+ipaddress+text2 all decoded into some field in table

Comment: Assuming what you're stating is true and correct: the best encryption algorithms are known to everybody. Again: using a home-grown encryption algorithm, relying on it's "secrecy", is [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_by_obscurity) and, again, a big no-no. There is never a need for the actual algorithm to stay secret. All that needs to remain secret is a private key (in most cases). See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3651090/215042) also.

Comment: ok, and where do you save the key? on sql\hardcoded?

Comment: Assuming ASP.Net (from your tags) you might save the key in the Web.Config. But it can be stored anywhere, ranging from a random file, the registy, a remote host and even in a "vault" using [DPAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx). And anything in between. Whatever the case might be, remember that: "Once you're on the other side of the airtight hatchway, all bets are off". Use correct (file/registry/whatever) permissions etc. and let the OS/platform/framework handle the rest. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2787875/215042) also.

Comment: how you recommend to hide the key from anyone who have access to server with production files?

Comment: Hiding the key once someone has "root access" to the host is the least of your problems. Again: see [this question+answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2787875/215042). Also have a look at [this blogpost](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/02/keeping-private-keys-private.html)